# Bootstrap onClick button event

Tags: javascript, jquery-events

This seems a silly question but just got bootstrap and it doesn't gives any examples on the website about adding a Javascript callback to a button...

Tried setting my button an id flag and then

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="rectButton" class="btn">Rectangle</button>
  <button class="btn">Circle</button>
  <button class="btn">Triangle</button>
  <button class="btn">Line</button>
  <button class="btn">Curve</button>
  <button class="btn">Pic</button>
  <button class="btn">Text</button>
  <button class="btn">Gradient</button>
</div>
```

I want to add a callback to Rectangle button...

```
$('#rectButton').on('show', function (e) {
    //ACTION
})
```

cant get the point of bootstrap callbacks.

All I could found on the web is oriented to Rails + Bootstrap... no bootstrap and JS only.

Comment: Do you mind also including the html code for your button please?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no `show` event in js - you need to bind your button either to the `click` event:

```
$('#id').on('click', function (e) {

     //your awesome code here

})
```

Mind that if your button is inside a `form`, you may prefer to bind the whole form to the `submit` event.

Comment: Still not working.. I have this button: <button id="rectButton" class="btn">Rectangle</button> inside a btn-group and the code is $('#rectButton').on('click', function (e) { // MY CODE });

Comment: Just copying your latest code, perfectly working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JUfBv/). Anyway bootstrap is just about presentation, nothing to to with js [besides some little optional plugin].

Comment: not working to me... I don't know what I'm missing... Do I have to include something else?

Comment: Well the fiddle just includes jQuery - if your code includes it too, please edit your question with the whole code so we can guess.

Comment: I can't get this to work with bootstrap 3.0.0 ... @JuanCB what do you mean by including jquery solved the problem? I've tried to use exactly what is in that jfiddle, but no luck...

Comment: For bootstrap 3 i used this `function runWorkflow() {//code}` with `<input type="submit" value="Run Workflow" class="btn btn-success" onclick="runWorkflow()" />`

Comment: @ZachM. don't use intrusive JS - anyways bootstrap has no interaction with buttons/forms whatsoever.

Comment: Ah yes, I see your point.  The application I am developing is for internal use and was just throwing out an idea, you are right though.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you had dynamically created buttons on your page, the

```
$("#your-bs-button's-id").on("click", function(event) {
                       or
$(".your-bs-button's-class").on("click", function(event) {
```

methods won't work because they only work on current elements (not future elements). Instead you need to reference a parent item that existed at the initial loading of the web page.

```
$(document).on("click", "#your-bs-button's-id", function(event) {
                       or more generally
$("#pre-existing-element-id").on("click", ".your-bs-button's-class", function(event) {
```

There are many other references to this issue on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Comment: Thanks for the `$(document).on("click` hint, that the above example does not work in future elements