# Unable to submit a form when click "input-group-btn"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a search bar using [Bootstrap#input-groups-buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-buttons)

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action=".">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search ...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </form>
```

When I press Enter, the form could be submitted successfully,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=test
```

However, when I click the button "Go", nothing happened.

How could I submit the form data when button is click?

Comment: Change the button type as submit. <button class="btn btn-default" `type="submit"`>Go!</button>. Check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp :)

Comment: Appreciate deeply for your help, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @EugineJoseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the button type as submit.

`<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>`.

Check for details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your form has the id of myForm

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" form="myForm" value="Submit">Go!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am betting you just need to bind the button to execute your event handler on click events - bootstrap handles the presentation, but you would also want something like jQuery to specify how to handle UI events.
You might want to read: [Bootstrap onClick button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081640/bootstrap-onclick-button-event)